# ng-file-upload returns 401

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload PDF to a Spring MVC back server on a **different port**. I have another requests made with normal **$http**, but when I use the Upload object I always get error **401**. I can see on the browser's network tab that ***Cookie*** header is not send, but in the other cases it does.

Here is my code:

```
Upload.upload({
    url: $http.defaults.backUrl + '/oficio/upload',
    data: {file: file, 'username': 'Alex'},
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function (resp) {
    console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
}, function (resp) {
    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
}, function (evt) {
    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
});
```

The request goes through my ***CORS*** filter, I'm sure because it sets the right headers, but the request doesn't send the ***Cookie*** header:

[image]

And this is the response:

[image]

When use $http, I don't get that error, this is a sample request with $http:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $http.defaults.backUrl + '/oficio/upload',
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
});
```

[image]

When $http I can get the file, but can´t track the progress.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you must check: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#java. There're some ways to solve this in **Java**.

Comment: @developer033 Sure, that was the first place I checked for information, but couldn't find anything that solves the problem. Thanks for the response.